# split into array and pass as arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, parameter-passing, apply

I have a string that I want to break and pass half of it like a parameter in a function. But the function treat the parameter like a entire piece.Example: `aaa,bbb,ccc` (3 parameters) but it understands one parameter `'aaa,bbb,ccc'`. How do I do this?

```
var text = "aaa,bbb,ccc@dd,eee,fff"
var itens_menu = text.split('@');
var item_menu1 = itens_menu[0];
var item_menu2 = itens_menu[1];

item = Menu(itens_menu[0]);
item2 = Menu(itens_menu[1]);


function Menu()
{
    var ItemText = arguments[0];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.split()` each of the values again. But you also need to pass to Menu the correct variable. You were passing in `itens_menu[0]`, but you should be passing in `item_menu1`.

## Option 1: Using the arguments

```js
var text = "aaa,bbb,ccc@dd,eee,fff"
var itens_menu = text.split('@');
var item_menu1 = itens_menu[0].split(',');
var item_menu2 = itens_menu[1].split(',');

var item = Menu(item_menu1);
var item2 = Menu(item_menu2);


function Menu() {
  var ItemText = arguments[0]; // this is the array
  console.log(ItemText);
  
  // if you are wanting to first value of the array, you would do
  // console.log(ItemText[0]) which would be either aaa, or dd
}
```

---

## Option 2: Using `apply`

If you were expecting to have all the values handed to `Menu` as individual arguments, you would need to [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the array to `Menu`. Then when you reference the arguments object, you would get string values back:

```js
var text = "aaa,bbb,ccc@dd,eee,fff"
var itens_menu = text.split('@');
var item_menu1 = itens_menu[0].split(',');
var item_menu2 = itens_menu[1].split(',');

var item = Menu.apply(null, item_menu1);
var item2 = Menu.apply(null, item_menu2);


function Menu() {
  var ItemText = arguments[0];
  console.log(ItemText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `.split` again, and also you can pass the **array** items as single argument:

```
var text = "aaa,bbb,ccc@dd,eee,fff"
var itens_menu = text.split('@');
var item_menu1 = itens_menu[0].split(',');
var item_menu2 = itens_menu[1].split(',');

var item = Menu.apply(null, item_menu1);
var item2 = Menu.apply(null, item_menu2);


function Menu() {
  console.log(arguments); // you'll have all the items as a single argument

  // so
  console.log(arguments[0]); 
  //this will return aaa for "item_menu1" and dd for "item_menu2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "aaa,bbb,ccc@dd,eee,fff"
var itens_menu = text.split(',');

item = Menu(itens_menu[0]);
item2 = Menu(itens_menu[1]);


function Menu()
{
    var ItemText = arguments[0];
    alert(ItemText);
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the OP's code? Looks like you just added an `alert`. Please explain what you did and why.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
var
    text = "aaa,bbb,ccc@dd,eee,fff",

    items_menu = text.split('@'),

    item_menu1 = items_menu[0],
    item_menu2 = items_menu[1],

    item  = Menu.apply(null, item_menu1.split(',')),
    item2 = Menu.apply(null, item_menu2.split(','));


function Menu(entry1, entry2, entry3) {

    console.log('arguments[0] : ', arguments[0]);
    console.log('arguments[1] : ', arguments[1]);
    console.log('arguments[2] : ', arguments[2]);

    return {
        entry1: entry1,
        entry2: entry2,
        entry3: entry3
    };
}


console.log('item : ', item);
console.log('item2 : ', item2);
```